# Calculate difference in years of two dates in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, difference

I have a data frame and I want to calculate the difference in years of two columns (Let's called id "Age").

I am having problems adjusting it to the date of the second column. Although, I managed to do it according to Sys.Date():

```
require(eeptools)
require(ggplot2)
DT$Age<-age_calc(DT$DateBirth, enddate=Sys.Date(), units="years", 
precise=T)
```

But, when I changed Sys.Date() to the name of the column (Which is called DateUpdated):

```
DT<-data.table(Id=c(1,2,3),DateBirth=c("01/01/1990 
","06/05/1980","07/09/2000"),DateUpdated=c("01/01/2019","03/04/2019",
"06/05/2019"),Age=c(29,38,18))

DT[,DateBirth:=as.Date(DateBirth,format= "%d/%m/%Y")]
DT[,DateUpdated:=as.Date(DateUpdated,format= "%d/%m/%Y")]

DT$Age<-age_calc(DT$DateBirth, enddate=DateUpdated, units="years", 
precise=T)
```

It returns the following error:

> Error in age_calc(DT$DateBirth, enddate = DateUpdated, units = "years",  : object 'DateUpdated' not found

Can someone give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give reference of the data.table that you are applying the function to

```
library(eeptools)  
library(data.table)

DT[, new := age_calc(DateBirth, DateUpdated, units="years", precise=T)]  

DT
#   Id  DateBirth DateUpdated Age  new
#1:  1 1990-01-01  2019-01-01  29 29.00
#2:  2 1980-05-06  2019-04-03  38 38.91
#3:  3 2000-09-07  2019-05-06  18 18.66
```

OR

```
age_calc(DT$DateBirth, DT$DateUpdated, units="years", precise=T)
#[1] 29.00 38.91 18.66
```